# How to add complete handler to an Observable outside of subscribe?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an `AsyncIterable` sourced from a database query interface that needs to be manually closed once the iteration is complete.

I need to create an observable from my `AsyncIterable` in such a way that would let me provide my own `complete`.

I know I can handle `complete` inside `subscribe`, but I do not want to subscribe to it, I need an `Observable` that would handle it automatically...

```
function fromQuery<T>(exec: QueryExecutor<T>): Observable<T> {
    const data: AsyncIterable<T> = exec.query();

    return from(data); // fails to release the source

    // I need to return an Observable that would always call
    // exec.release() inside its 'complete' handler.

    // how to do that?
}
```

How to finish `fromQuery` so that the returned `Observable` would guarantee invocation of `exec.release()` upon completion for any subscriber?

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap or https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize

Comment: Thank you! Operator `finalize` did it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Eddy Lin, operator [finalize](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) did the trick:

```
function fromQuery<T>(exec: QueryExecutor<T>): Observable<T> {
    const data: AsyncIterable<T> = exec.query();

    return from(data).pipe(finalize(() => {
        exec.release();
    }));
}
```

**update:**

As per Martin's suggestion, I tried with `tap`, but it did not work as expected:

```
return from(data).pipe(tap({
    complete() {
        // this handler is allowed, but it is never called
    },
    finalize() {
        // this one is called the same as for operator "finalize"
    }
}));
```

Comment: Just be aware, that `finalize` isn't the same as a complete handler.

Comment: @martin Could you elaborate on that? And is there a better implementation?

Comment: `finalize()` adds a dispose handler to the chain which means it'll be called when the chain is being disposed. This happens when the chain completes, errors or the Observable is unsubscribed. With `tap({ complete: .. })` you'll add only `complete` handler.

Comment: @martin I have tried to use `tap`, it didn't work as expected. RxJs allows both `complete` and `finalize` handlers, and while `finalize` is called the same as with operator `finalize`, `complete` is never called. (see update in my answer).